# Comparing dates in java is giving wrong results

Tags: java, datetime

I'm comparing dates using following code

```
String sCreatedDate = "30.07.201514:57:03";
String sModifiedDate = "30.07.201515:40:34";            
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyyHH:MM:SS");

Date d1 = parser.parse(sCreatedDate);
Date d2 = parser.parse(sModifiedDate);         
System.out.println(d1.before(d2));
```

It printing `false`, but I'm expecting it to print `true`.

can you please explain me what I'm doing wrong in this code?

However the above code is working fine for below dates and printing true value:

```
String sCreatedDate = "23.07.201507:25:35";
String sModifiedDate = "23.07.201507:26:07";
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the end of your format, you've used `MM` (months) instead of `mm` (minutes).

```
String sCreatedDate = "30.07.201514:57:03";
String sModifiedDate = "30.07.201515:40:34";            
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyyHH:mm:ss");//mm small
Date d1 = parser.parse(sCreatedDate);
Date d2 = parser.parse(sModifiedDate);         
System.out.println(d1.before(d2));//true
```

Comment: A clear explanatory sentence is more useful than a cryptic comment.